# Emails are not accepted because of domain's\n550-5.7.26 DMARC policy on gmail

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, yahoo-mail

We are using external remote server to send mails which requires autentification.
Mails are sent through Laravel application. On every mail client emails pass regullary except google and yahoo mail where we get message:

Unauthenticated email from *******.com is not accepted due to domain's 550-5.7.26 DMARC policy.

Are there any other configuration on server or laravel app other than ones in config/mail.php?

Any thougths?

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=*******.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*****
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

We are using this configuration in .env file ...